# Regex Capture Second Word Within Capture Group

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to capture the second word within a capture string I grabbed using a positive look ahead. I want the second word within the string that comes before either a space followed by a quotation mark, a space followed by a open parentheses, or a space followed by the string "Jr."

Here is an example line:

> Anne R. Lomica "Lommy" (Datore)

This is my Regex so far:

```
(.+?(?=\ "|\ \(|,|\ Jr\.))
```

Which captures:

> Anne R. Lomica

But within that I want to capture:

> R.

In the example line:

> John Sean Fuller Jr.

I want to capture:

> Sean

How can I modify my existing Regex to capture the second word within what it already captures?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: it seems that this `"|\ ` is equal to `[" ]` and here (|,|\ |,|\  with [(, `]

Comment: did you want two captures? Did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/lS2uM2/1 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I only want to capture match 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
(\S+) \S+(?= "| \(|,|\ Jr\.)
```

Get the string you want from group index 1.

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lS2uM2/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\s]+[ ]([^\s]+)[ ].+(?=\ "|\ \(|,|\ Jr\.)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/3